# Intervalo de confiança de beta e de OR

Tags: r

Tenho um conjunto de dados para fazer a regressão logística da variável dependente parto que é qualitativa binária.

Utilizo o comando abaixo para obter o modelo logístico univariado no programa R:

```
GLM.1 <- glm(parto ~ serie, family=binomial(logit), data=Dataset)
```

Gostaria de saber qual comando do R devo usar para obter o INTERVALO DE CONFIANÇA DE BETA e também o INTERVALO DE CONFIANÇA DO OR para a variável independente serie.

Caso seja necessário utilizar um pacote específico do R para isso, gostaria de saber qual seria este pacote e qual função usar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o intervalo de confiança, existe a função `confint`

```
confint(GLM.1)
```

Segue um [link](http://www.estatisticacomr.uff.br/?p=598) que apresenta um detalhamento sobre Regressão Logística no `R` que pode te auxiliar com o cálculo da razão de chances

Comment: Obrigada Rafael Cunha, você me ajudou muito a resolver meu problema!!